# Calculate $f_{Y}(0.5)$ where $Y$ is defined using random variable $X$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable so:
$$
f_{X}(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{2\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{\pi} & -1<x<1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Also, lets define $Y$ to be:
$$
Y=\begin{cases}
X^{3} & X\geq0\\
X^{2} & X<0
\end{cases}
$$
I want to calculate $f_{Y}(0.5)$.
So I used transormation and got to:
$$
\begin{align*}
f_{Y}(y)&=\sum_{x\,g(x)=y,\,g'(x)\neq0}f_{X}(x)\cdot\frac{1}{|g'(x)|}=\frac{2\sqrt{1-\left(-\sqrt{y}\right)^{2}}}{\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{|2\left(-\sqrt{y}\right)|}+\frac{2\sqrt{1-\left(\sqrt[3]{y}\right)^{2}}}{\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{|3\left(\sqrt[3]{y}\right)^{2}|}\\&=\frac{2}{\pi}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-y}}{2|\sqrt{y}|}+\frac{\sqrt{1-y^{\frac{2}{3}}}}{3|y^{\frac{2}{3}}|}\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{\pi}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-y}}{2\sqrt{y}|}+\frac{\sqrt{1-y^{\frac{2}{3}}}}{3y^{\frac{2}{3}}}\right) & y>0\\
0 & y\leq0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$
where $g(x)=\begin{cases}
x^{3} & x\geq0\\
x^{2} & x<0
\end{cases}$. Then we get:
$$
f_{Y}(0.5)=\frac{2}{\pi}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-y}}{2\sqrt{y}|}+\frac{\sqrt{1-y^{\frac{2}{3}}}}{3y^{\frac{2}{3}}|}\right)\approx0.52322
$$
I want to find another way to do it. I'm trying to use convolution for that. But I can't seem to figure it out. How can I use Convolution to solve it?

Comment: Maybe something along these lines? $\mathbb{P}(Y \in \mathrm{d}y) =\mathbb{P}(Y \in \mathrm{d}y, X \geq 0) + \mathbb{P}(Y \in \mathrm{d}y, X < 0) = \mathbb{P}(X^3 \in \mathrm{d}y, X \geq 0) + \mathbb{P}(X^2 \in \mathrm{d}y, X < 0)$.

Comment: You may have to use symmetry of $X$ around $0$.